# how to store multiple characters in one variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I'm attempting to create a guessing game where everytime the user clicks a character it will be stored in a variable to form a string. Let's say for example...  (c t   p   i   j   a   r   a   v   s) so if the user clicks J A V A S C R I P T respectively, It will be stored in a variable as "javascript" and will be recognized as the correct answer .and my code looks like this:

```
clickcount = 0;
$(".gameletter").click(function() {
keyletter = $(this).attr("ID");
vars['m' + clickcount] = keyletter;
clickcount++;

}
});
```

but I don't know how to combine every keyletter to form a string... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array instead of an object to store the letters, and combine them into a string using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var clickcount = 0;
var letters = [];

$(".gameletter").click(function() {
    var letter = $(this).attr("ID");
    letters.push(letter);
    clickcount++;
});

// ...

var string = letters.join('');
```

Comment: `push()` would be better

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem by splitting the target word into an array and removing letters as they guess correctly. Once the word array length is 0, they have won:

```
var word = 'javascript'.split(''); // ['j', 'a', 'v', 'a' ...]

function guessLetter(guess) {
  if(word.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
    // remove correct letter guess from word
    word.splice(word.indexOf(guess), 1);
  }

  if(word.length === 0) {
    console.log('you win');
  }
}

guessLetter('j');
```